# Proposition about eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a real $2 \times 2$ matrix. If $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues, then $A^2$ has two distinct eigenvalues.
 Is it true or not?

Comment: No. Look for a diagonal counterexample.

Comment: The Eigenvalues of $A^2$ are those of $A$, squared. So you lose the sign...

Answer (score 1):

let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

then $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues but $A^2$ only has one : $1$